# Как соотносятся примеры из книг и реальная разработка?

Tags: javascript

Я изучаю JS по книгам роликам и на некоторых сайтах. И на везде приводятся примеры связь которых я не могу понять.

Допустим примеры с оператором if. Есть три переменные "a = 5","b = 4" и "x" если а больше b то х будет равен сумме а и b.

У меня возникает вопрос как этот пример связан с Web фронтендом и тд. То есть как я могу применить свои знания в реальной задаче? В том же CSS видно на примере прописал color и цвет изменился. А тут возникает чувство что я учу что то вообще не связанное с web программированием.

Comment: Вы уже изучили JS как язык? Если да, то следует изучать соответствующие фронтэнд технологии.

Comment: Javascript - это полноценный язык программирования, который не ограничивается только веб-фронтэндом. Но чтобы его грамотно использовать в вебе, надо знать, как минимум, основы языка и, в том числе, условные операторы. Не знаю, по каким именно источникам учитесь Вы, но крайне рекомендую вот этот ресурс: http://learn.javascript.ru/

Comment: на javascript пишется логика...серверная, клиентская, десктопная...оператор условия `if` один из основных аспектов, используемых повсеместно в коде...а `a` `b` `x` вам дают, чтобы вы поняли на легком примере что делает этот оператор, и смогли его использовать там где вам нужно было.

Comment: `То есть как я могу применить свои знания в реальной задаче? В том же CSS видно на примере прописал color и цвет изменился.` Колор.. Первое что в голову пришло - тема для пользователя. Самая убогая реализация - `if (theme = black) { document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black"; }` Не схоже ли с примером? Вообще, странные у вас вопросы на начальном этапе) чтобы понять надо не просто делать задачки а и самому думать как их можно будет применять на практике

Comment: Как уже сказали, https://learn.javascript.ru/ даёт очень хорошую инфу. На русскоязычном пространстве, наверное, лучшее учебное пособие. Если не слишком понятно, зачем нужны ифы, массивы, циклы и прочие алгоритмические штуки, то советую на всё том же ресурсе начать со второй части. Быстро осознать, что и первая, в общем-то, тоже пригодится, но хотя бы понять что к чему. Или же найти книгу HeadFirst JavaScript (есть в русском переводе) и начать с неё.

Comment: @InDevX `if (theme = black) {` - ай-ай-ай, не хорошо опечатываться в примерах)

Comment: Привоединяюсь к предыдущему висказыванию http://learn.javascript.ru - очень хорошее руководство в том числе и относительно вопросов по веб програмирования. поначалу кажется что идет нагроможденике ненужной теоретической информации, но в дальнейшем теоретические знания здорово пригодятся.

Comment: @grundy сутки на работе уже) больше не буду

Comment: @Grundy как ни печально, но он может и не ошибаться... но тогда это не учебный пример

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, все зависит от значения `black` :) но конкретно тут опечатка :)

Comment: Хороший пример, когда нужно использовать условие и с чем все сталкивались - это когда вы от сервера получили данные (например в JSON), но вам не нужно все данные выводить. И с помощью условий и других операций вы отбираете данные.

Comment: Как связан...  Вот будет у вас в макете калькулятор по ссуде. Как вы его заставите работать? `css`-ом?

Answer (score 4):

Если при начальном изучении языка вам давать примеры из реальной разработки, то вы просто ничего не поймёте и перестанете учить язык.

Примеры специально составляются так, чтобы каждый пример максимально ясно демонстрировал одну какую-то тему/нюанс/приём. Для этого пример и делают максимально очищенных от посторонних смыслов, которые бы только отвлекали.

Это как в первом классе буквы и слоги учат по "Мама мыла раму" а не по "Критике чистого разума" Канта.

Comment: Почему я вообще задал этот вопрос просто возникает чувство что учишь что то не то. То есть если в том же CSS я на реальном примере могу поменять цвет, шрифт. стиль и тп. То в JS я выучил этот оператор if, я знаю как он работает, а зачем он мне нужен, где я его могу применить не совсем понятно. Всё превращается в простую зубрёшку.

Comment: @nursultan.sadirbaev, на операторе `if` строится логика. То есть каждый раз, когда вам нужно делать разные вещи в зависимости от разных условий - вам не обойтись либо без `if`, либо какого-то более сложного способа задать ветвление. А такая потребность возникает всегда, когда на сайте есть что-то сложнее просто вёрстки. Ветвление, циклы, коллекции - это основы, без которых вы не создадите ничего кроме очень простенького сайта-визитки.

Answer (score -3):

Для фронт-энда важна инженерная часть и визуальная часть, которая строиться с помощью тэгов html и стилей CSS. js/jq бывает необходим для функций/технической части, например: свайп, кнопки по нажатию которых что-то происходить (добавление класса) и т.д. Иначе говоря «Сценарный Язык» необходим собственно для разных сценариев. Я никому не рекомендую загружать сайты js, использовать только минимум, иначе сайт может стать тяжелым. Кроме того, если позволяют серверные языки обходиться без js, то лучше использовать их (php например). В остальном изобилие js создают тормоза/зависания.

Дополню про условия... if, else, elseif... это всё условия для создания разных вариантов, которые зависят от идей и их реализации. Такие условия используются не только в js, но и в: php, smarty..

Если ты, друг, хочешь заниматься конкретно визуальной частью, то начни с идеи. Поставь себе вопрос - Что нужно построить? После этого уже - Как? Анализируй варианты, если есть несколько разных способов решений, выбирай эффективный с твоей точки зрения. Да,да, - формируй свой взгляд, свой опыт. Реализовывай.

https://habr.com/ru/post/341626/

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92884/discussion-on-answer-by-vladimir-rodichev-------).

Comment: https://m.habr.com/ru/post/341626/